# Barplot or ggplot with the header of a dataframe

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to obtain a ggplot or a barplot with the header of a dataframe as the x of this barplot.

```
                              colSums.df4..na.rm...TRUE. 
11+12                          149
11+13                           59
11+2                            74
11+20                            7
11+23                          118
```

I would like to obtain a ggplot with the header(11+12,11+13 ...) as x and the "colSums.df4..na.rm...TRUE" as y.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please share reproducible example `dput(mydata)`.

Comment: Try this: `barplot(mtcars[, "cyl"], names.arg = rownames(mtcars))`

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach. Transfer the rownames as a new variable using `rownames_to_column()` and then for the sake of the exercise change that long name. Here the code using some `tidyverse` functions and `ggplot2`:

```
library(tidyverse)
#Code
df %>% rownames_to_column('Var') %>%
  rename(Value=colSums.df4..na.rm...TRUE.) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=Var,y=Value))+
  geom_bar(stat='identity',color='black',fill='magenta')+
  theme_bw()
```

Output:

[image]

Some data used:

```
#Data
df <- structure(list(colSums.df4..na.rm...TRUE. = c(149L, 59L, 74L, 
7L, 118L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("11+12", "11+13", 
"11+2", "11+20", "11+23"))
```